# Distribute Swift app without Swift framework

Tags: swift, frameworks

I read in the [blog post about the Swift 5.0 release](https://swift.org/blog/swift-5-released/) that

> [...] applications written in Swift no longer need to be distributed with the Swift runtime libraries, reducing download size.

When I tried to archive and export an app it still had the framework. macOS Deployment Target set to macOS 10.14, Swift Language Version is Swift 5.

How can I export a Swift 5 app without bundling the Swift framework?

Edit: I created a Cocoa app using the wizard, and exported it. The export contains the Frameworks folder with the Swift libraries. I was, however, able to delete the Frameworks folder. The app still runs, and the bundle size went from ~11 MB to ~83kB.